# VBA: Is there a way to have an If statement that only accepts values that are in a range in a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Example:

```
For i = number of accepted values 
 in column A,

If (my userform input) = (one of the accepted values in column A) then

    It’s accepted

Else

    It’s not

End if

Next i

‘A1 = contains header

‘A2 = 1
‘A3 = 54
‘A4 = abc
```

So if someone inputs 1, 54, or abc in the user form it will accept it since it is one of the approved values in a certain spreadsheet

I know it’s more complicated than above, but is there a way to do that?

I didn’t try to do this yet, as I haven’t had time, but I had the thought so I wanted to put it here before I forgot.

Comment: `if not iserror(Application.Match(my userform input, range("A1:A10"), 0)) then`?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right I would put all the values in question in a dictionary first and then get the input you would like to check.

```
Sub validateInput()
    
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A2:A4")
    Dim sngCell As Range
    For Each sngCell In rg
        dict(sngCell.Value) = sngCell.Value
    Next

    ' just an example
    Dim inpVal As Variant
    inpVal = 54
    If dict.Exists(inpVal) Then
        Debug.Print "Ok"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not ok"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Match a UserForm Input in a Worksheet Column

```vb
Sub MatchUserFormInput()
    
    ' Reference the workbook and worksheet.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Reference the range.
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        If rCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No data in column.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Convert the input string to the correct type.
    
    ' Emulating a user form input i.e. e.g. input from a text box.
    ' Anything in a text box is a string (even numbers).
    Dim InputString As String: InputString = "1"
    
    If Len(InputString) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No input retrieved.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' It is assumed that the data in the column are strings or numbers
    ' (not numbers as text).
    Dim InputValue:
    If IsNumeric(InputString) Then
        InputValue = CDbl(InputString)
    Else
        InputValue = CStr(InputString)
    End If
    
    ' Inform if there was a match.
    
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(InputValue, rg, 0)) Then
        MsgBox "It's accepted.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "It's not accepted.", vbExclamation
    End If
 
End Sub
```